# Complete file from command line

Tags: bash

I have a situation where I would like to complete a config file in an adhoc way. I would like to do this by executing a bash script.

The initial file would be called conf.ini and looks like:

```
[dev]
parameter_dev = <value_dev>
[test]
parameter_test = <value_test>
```

I would like to execute a script that would be able to replace <value_dev> and <value_test> into their real values given on command line.

What would be the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Add examples of `<value_dev>` and `<value_test>` to your question.

Comment: `sed -i -e '/^parameter_dev/s/<value_dev>/real_dev_value/' -e '/^parameter_test/s/<value_test>/real_test_value/' path/to/conf.ini` If you want to pass variable for, e.g. `real_dev_value`, then double-quote the sed expressions  and use the variable name, e.g. `sed -i -e "/^parameter_dev/s/<value_dev>/$real_dev_value/" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update `config.ini`, the stream-editor `sed` can be used to edit `config.ini` in place and replace both `<value_dev>` and `<value_test>` with any values you like. To do so you will use the normal substitute form `s/find/replace/` and you will include a pattern match before the substituted to only perform the substitution if the start of the line matches the pattern. For example for `<value_dev>` you can use an expression such as:

```sh
sed -i -e '/^parameter_dev/s/<value_dev>/real_dev_value/' conf.ini
```

The with only match a line beginning with `"parameter_dev"` and then will find `<value_dev>` in the line and replace it with `real_dev_value`. If you are calling it from within a script and want to replace with the value contained in the variable `$real_dev_value`, then you must use double-quotes instead of single-quotes so that variable-expansion takes place.

You can handle both replacements in a single call by simply adding another expression, e.g.

```sh
sed -i -e '/^parameter_dev/s/<value_dev>/real_dev_value/' -e \
          '/^parameter_test/s/<value_test>/real_test_value/' conf.ini
```

The option `-i` tells `sed` to edit the file in-place. Each `-e` option introduces a new expression to be applied to the file.

If using a variable for the replaced value, the double-quoted form allowing variable expansion would be:

```sh
sed -i -e "/^parameter_dev/s/<value_dev>/$real_dev_value/" -e \
          "/^parameter_test/s/<value_test>/$real_test_value/" conf.ini
```

Either form, using fixed strings or variables for replacement can be used on the command line or called from within a script.

Let me know if you have any questions.